# add a link to a script code

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, window.open

I have this script that for now has static values:

```
var Lines = [];

var addLine = function(symbol, price, change, percent) {
  Lines.push('<tr>' +
    '<td class="symbol" >' + symbol  + '</td>' +
    '<td class="price"  >' + price   + '</td>' +
    '<td class="change" >' + change  + '</td>' +
    '<td class="percent">' + percent + '</td>' +
    '</tr>');
};

//  function to get data
function StockPriceTicker() {
  var Symbol = "",
      CompName = "",
      Price = "",
      ChnageInPrice = "",
      PercentChnageInPrice = "";

  var CNames = "TSLA,HPQ,VRSK,CERN,KHC,EXPD";
  var flickerAPI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + CNames + "%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";

  var StockTickerXML = $.get(flickerAPI, function(xml) {
    $(xml).find("quote").each(function() {
      Symbol = $(this).attr("symbol");
      $(this).find("Name").each(function() {
        CompName = $(this).text();
      });
      $(this).find("LastTradePriceOnly").each(function() {
        Price = $(this).text();
      });
      $(this).find("Change").each(function() {
        ChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
      });
      $(this).find("PercentChange").each(function() {
        PercentChnageInPrice = $(this).text();
      });

      var PriceClass = "GreenText",
          PriceIcon = "up_green";

      if (parseFloat(ChnageInPrice) < 0) {
        PriceClass = "RedText";
        PriceIcon = "down_red";
      }


      var htmlSymbol,
          htmlPrice,
          htmlChange,
          htmlPercent;


      htmlSymbol = "<span class='quote'>" + Symbol + " </span></span>";
      htmlPrice = "<span class='" + PriceClass + "'>";
      htmlPrice = htmlPrice + parseFloat(Price).toFixed(2) + " ";

      htmlChange = parseFloat(Math.abs(ChnageInPrice)).toFixed(2) + "<span class='" + PriceIcon + "'></span>";

      htmlPercent = parseFloat(Math.abs(PercentChnageInPrice.split('%')[0])).toFixed(2) + "%";


      // use here the function defined above.
      addLine(htmlSymbol, htmlPrice, htmlChange, htmlPercent);

    });



    $body.empty().html(Lines.join(''));

    // we reset the content of Lines for the next interval
    Lines = [];

  });
}
```

Here the [running code script](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXRvXj).
What i want to accomplish is to add a link to every "symbol" contained in "Cnames" var.
The link is something like "https://www.example.com/chart/?symbol=Ticker", where "Ticker" is the "symbol" that i'm clicking in that moment.
So for example, when i click on TSLA, i want that it will open a popup window (like a window.open function) that point exactly to "https://www.example.com/chart/?symbol=TSLA".
The link will be equal for everyone, except for the last words after the "=" symbol.
Is it possible to show me a portion of code tha can to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you need this:

```
'<td class="symbol" > <a href="https://www.example.com/chart/?symbol=' + ($(symbol).text())  + '" target="_blank">' + symbol + '</a> </td>'
```

Comment: Almost! there is something wrong, i guess with the 2 """ after the href tag. I've updated my codepen link above, so you can see the result and the full link after clicking the cnames.

Comment: yes that was a typo.. and there is a " at the end of the link. check my update

Comment: and there is one more problem. you are not just sending a symbol but also span around it. so will need to extract text from it.. updated answer accordingly

Comment: yes i noticed that right now, it doesn't work properly. There is no way around?

Comment: did you try my update? it is working fine on your codepen script.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't run the last of yours updates. Now it works properly! Can you please explain to me how did you excluded the span elements and sended just the symbol? Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: Your welcome. using jquery .text() method, it can take any selector or a new element. reference: http://api.jquery.com/text/